# Honeycomb Actionbar SearchView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I'm working on a Honeycomb app that needs a SearchView in the Actionbar, but I'm rather confused as to what I need to do to implement it.

I don't think the documentation covers everything for Honeycomb, seems like it was just done for the mobile versions of Android.

I've been looking at this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html

My data comes from a SQLite database, and I've already got database query for searching, so that's not a problem.

Any help?

**Edit:**
Well, looking at the feedback I'm getting here, I can see that I'm apparently not explaining myself properly... Can't do it any better though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try looking at this page instead:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I'd been looking all over the documentation, but decided to do something else. This is way to complicated for my use.